# why does rangeOfString no longer work inside if statement only for 5.1 simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, if-statement

Why is this not working in 5.1 simulator but DOES work in 4.2 4.3 5.0 ???

OSXLion 10.7.4
XCode 4.3.3

```
 if ([email.text rangeOfString:@"@"].location == NSNotFound) {

    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email" message:@"Please provide email address" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cool" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

}
else {
    work...work...work...
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does "no longer work" mean _exactly_?

Comment: it executes the else statement

Comment: Have you logged the contents of `email.text`. These kind of issues are more than likely your fault rather than a bug or undocumented API change. If the contents seem to be correct try cleaning your project and reseting the contents of the simulator.

Comment: @Joe  Thank You, I never knew you could clean the simulator with 'reset' ...that did the trick.  Thanks agin.

Answer (score 1):

If you have confirmed the email address does not contain an `@` then it sounds like the simulator may be running an older version of your code. I recommend cleaning your project and [resetting the contents and settings](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/25-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html) of the simulator. To reset the simulator, while it is the frontmost open application choose *iOS Simulator* **>** *Reset Content and Settings*.